# Impossible to load file from a relative path using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery I'm trying to load a html file(page.html) using jquery from an other subfolder(folder2\index.html) of the parent folder(project) ; but it gives the following error : "InternalError: too much recursion" .
Here is the hierarchy of the sample :

```
|-Project
  |-folder2
  |  |-page.html (html to load)
  |
  |-folder1
     |-index.html(page where the loading script is called from)
```

Here is the code I'm using

```
$( "#destination-ressource" ).load( "../folder2/page.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {  
    //do somthing
});
```

when xhr.statusText is inspected it gives the following message:   "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

I also tried to replace

> "../folder2/page.html"

by

> "./folder2/page.html"

but it doesn't work .

Comment: If project is root then `/folder2/page.html` will work

Comment: Are you also using the load function somewhere in page.html?

Comment: the folder Project is the root and I'm trying to load the "page.html" from "index.html"

Comment: Is it being used in page.html also? can u post the stacktrace that you see in the dev tools?

Comment: @everconfusedGuy :  it is no used from page.html ;but in index.html. Here are the details of stacktrace from the console : "InternalError: too much recursion"   and when xhr.statusText is inspected it gives the following message: "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

Comment: Try out the comment by @DarrenSweeney or put in the absolute URL if that doesnt work

Comment: What is the absolute URI of the page? I'd guess your problems have to do with either working on the file system instead of HTTP or with directories that aren't published on the web server.

Comment: @Quentin :
-My files are not published in the server.
I quickly tested within a server ;and it works file keeping the URL"../folder2/page.html" ;However,I'm not targeting a server for publication.
-the absolute path is file:///C:/project/folder/page.html (OK)

Comment: @RanDeloun — That's your problem then. Ajax doesn't work without a server.

Answer (score 0):

If your script are in separate file js then the relative path is from the path of that script, not from your html file

Comment: That's completely wrong. URIs in JavaScript are always relative to the URL of the execution environment (the page) not the script.